# Lotusscript Dir$ giving "illegal function call" with UNC path

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Was getting error "illegal function call" using Dir$() in Lotusscript with a UNC path (\serverName\shareName*) 
This was only happening in the Test environment
When troubleshooting tried a dir at a cmd prompt, and got following error
c:> Dir \serverName\shareName\dirName

> "No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept."

When I tried this on a different share there was no problem, which is how I found the solution.

SOLUTION - See first answer below 
(Logging this in case anyone else gets the issue)

Comment: This question & solution would have saved me several hours work. 
I created the question & solution to help someone with the same issue.
Downvoting this is doing a disservice to anyone with this particular issue in the future!!!

I will move some of the text from the solution to the question.  Please remove the downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
The share on the Windows server had a limit of 3 on number of connections
(Folder Properties / Sharing / Advanced Sharing =
"Limit the number of simultaneous users to:  3"  )

Not sure why attempting to do a Dir$ seemed to push it past the limit!
but upping the connection limit on the Share solved the problem.
When troubleshooting also got the following error at a cmd prompt 
c:> Dir \serverName\shareName\dirName

> "No more connections can be made to this remote computer at this time because there are already as many connections as the computer can accept."

(was ok with a different share, which is how I found the solution)